# Opening a link in a new page highjacks the referrer page

Tags: html

A client wishes to have a link that opens a new window and shows the website of an investment company.
Pretty straight forward so far.

So I create this link

```
<a href="https://webbroker.td.com/waw/idp/login.htm" target="_blank">Click Me</a>
```

The client then tells me that the page is acting all weird. So I test it and he's right, it's acting very strange.

Here's what my tests shows.

**Firefox mac:** Page opens, then closes itself and returns to the window with the client's website where it then changes the URL to the one that is suppose to open.

**Safari mac and Chrome mac:** Page opens, then closes itself and returns to the window with the client's website

**Client's IE:** opening and closing multiple windows (his words, didn't test it myself);

Instead of redirecting to the page itself, I changed the link to go to the homepage. User will now have to click on "Login" to access the page we wanted originally. Guess what? It does the same thing.

[Here's a simplified fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wN79k/1/) You'll see it's pretty straight forward.

Now I know that the problem isn't from my side but on the investment site. They seem to dynamically add some parameters to the URL for security reasons I suppose.

My question is: how can I avoid all this non sense and simply open the page without it closing? Can someone explain to my why it's doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the login link myself (in Chrome) and it does the same thing.. closes itself.. You should contact their web-designers and report the problem. I succeeded to click on Stop loading button and look through page. Everything is "ok" except that thing it closes. Contact them and wait for response/fix.

Comment: That's what I thought but I couldn't find the information to contact the webmaster. I guess I'll contact the general inquiries. Thanks anyway.